# Solving systems of nonlinear equations

Tags: matlab, system, equation-solving

Help. I am trying to solve this system of nonlinear equations in MATLAB for a homework assignment. I have tried wolfram alpha and this [online equation solver](http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/equations/solve/advanced.jsp#c=solve_advancedsolveequations&v1=.75%2a%281100%29=+x%2a10%5E%286.82485%20-%20943.453/%28T+239.711%29%29%0A25%2a1100=%281-x%29%2a10%5E%286.88555-1175.817/%28T+224.887%29&v2=x%0AT), and neither of them work.

I have tried my graphing calculator and it keeps saying non algebraic variable or expression.

These are my two equations in two unknowns:

```
.75*(1100)= x*10^(6.82485-943.453/(T+239.711))

25*1100=(1-x)*10^(6.88555-1175.817/(T+224.887)
```

I don't quite understand how to use MATLAB to solve this system. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You want the function fsolve in Matlab. Define a function myfun that returns [0,0] at the solution, then run fsolve(myfun,x0). x0 is a guess for the solution.

Define myfun:

```
function F = myfun(x)
F = [<put modified eqt1 here>;
<put modified eqt2 here>;];
```

Save it. Then solve:

```
x0 = [1,1];      
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0,options) % Call solver
```

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, your function should probably look like this: 

`function y = my_fun(x)

y(1) = x(1)*10^(6.82485-943.453/(x(2)+239.711)) - 0.75*1100;

y(2) = (1-x(1))*10^(6.88555-1175.817/(x(2)+224.887) - 25*1100;

end`

For more details, see the doc on `fsolve`: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html. You need the Optimization Toolbox.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and still leave some for OP to do (imo, since this is an assignment, that's the best way to answer)